# lambda with nested if's weird syntax

Tags: python, lambda

I like using lambdas more then I should so more than once I wanted to solve nested if statement with it and failed using standard syntax.

But then I tried something like this:

```
lambda x: 1 if x > 100 else 2 if x > 50 else 3
```

Surprisingly it works, although proper function is supposed to have `elif`:

```
def foo(x):
    if x > 100:
        return 1
    elif x > 50:
        return 2
    else:
        return 3
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: I'd recommend `lambda x: 1 if x > 100 else (2 if x > 50 else 3)` for readability because explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: Why do you think a proper function should use `elif`?

Comment: @Gribouillis I wish you wrote that as an answer as it pretty much explains what and why :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend

```
lambda x: 1 if x > 100 else (2 if x > 50 else 3)
```

for readability because explicit is better than implicit.

Indeed, due to evaluation from left to right, the ternary operator is right associative as the following code demonstrates

```
def f(a, b):
    return 1 if a else 2 if b else 3

def left(a, b):
    return (1 if a else 2) if b else 3

def right(a, b):
    return 1 if a else (2 if b else 3)

tpl = "{:^8}{:^8}{:^6}{:^6}{:^6}"
print(tpl.format('a', 'b', 'f', 'left', 'right'))
for (a, b) in [(False, False),(False, True),(True, False),(True, True)]:
    print(tpl.format(repr(a), repr(b), f(a,b), left(a,b), right(a,b)))

""" my output ->

a       b      f    left right 
False   False    3     3     3   
False    True    2     2     2   
True   False    1     3     1   
True    True    1     1     1  

"""
```

The ternary expression always gives the same result as the expression where everything after the first else is parenthesized.

When the conditions are `(x>100)` and `(x>50)`, the case `True, False` can never happen, so the three expressions give the same result. Nevertheless, *explicit is better than implicit*!

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to use elif. You can use `if` inside another `else` which is the same as what lambda function is doing:

```
def foo(x):
    if x > 100:
        return 1
    else:
        if x > 50:
           return 2
        else:
           return 3
```

Comment: I also like `lambda x: 3 - bisect.bisect_left([50, 100], x)` :-)

Comment: @Gribouillis Sure, if you are searching in an interval I think bisect is the way to go.

Comment: @ayhan I know how it functions and what is the flow but the syntax seemed strange

Answer (score 0):

You are actually using something like elif by writing

```
else 2 if x > 50
```

in

```
lambda x: 1 if x > 100 else 2 if x > 50 else 3
```

Its just a different way of writing something like elif in lambda

Answer (score 0):

```
lambda x: 1 if x > 100 else 2 if x > 50 else 3
```

Means :

```
# 1 if x > 100 
if x > 100:
    return 1 
# else 2 if x > 50 else 3
else:
    # 2 if x > 50 else 3
    if x > 50:
        return 2
    else:
        return 3
```

Which does the same thing that your second snippet with `elif`.

You cannot use `elif` in a lambda expression. As far as I know, it should raise a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 0):

You have *concatenated* two [conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

One

```
2 if x > 50 else 3
```

provides the value for the *else clause* of the other.

```
1 if x > 100 else ...
```

---

You have the conditional expression

```
x if C else y
```

where

```
x = 1
C = 100
```

and

```
y = 2 if x > 50 else 3
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), `y` can be an expression so `y` can be a conditional expression.